# Is this loss function convex?

Tags: regression, gradient-descent

I am working on a small project to understand gradient descent. I am trying to model noisy cubic data with the ideal cubic polynomial. I am using linear regression with the least-squares method with my loss function as MSE. And applying gradient descent to find the optimal coefficients.

Considering just 1 training example I have

$$(y - [ax^3+bx^2+cx +d])^2$$

Is this convex with respect to the coefficients $a,b,c,d$?

Comment: Can you take the derivative of that function with respect to $a$?  The second derivative will contain all the information you need...

Comment: I see I have positive second derivatives, besides d which is just a constant. Am I allowed to assume my cost function can attain a local minimum? I understand a global is not possible because it is not strictly convex in some of the parameters.

Comment: It is strictly convex with respect to the coefficients, however, so a global minimum given the $y$ and $x$ values is obtainable.